# NSDate date in objective-c gives different datetime than Date() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I understand that IOS uses place independent times unless specified otherwise.  However, for an unknown reason when I log to console [NSDate date] from Objective-C, I am getting the actual time where I'm located whereas when I print to console Date() from swift, I'm getting a getting Greenwich meantime.

In objective-C the first mention of date in the method is:

```
   __block NSDate* rightNow = [NSDate date];
    LogDebug(@"right now%@",rightNow);
/logs as: right nowFri Oct 26 14:18:37 2018
```

In swift, the first mention of date in the method is:

```
 let now =  Date()
        print("right now date is",now)
//Prints as: right now date is 2018-10-26 18:19:10 +0000
```

I do set formats using dateformatter for date in other methods in the Objective-C class, but I don't see how they could carry over into this method.

What could account for there being different?  Is there a way to force them to be one or the other?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The dates are most likely the same, what differs is the way they print in Swift vs. Objective-C.

Comment: They are the same dates. It's just a difference in how they are being printed. None of this affects the functionality of your code.

Comment: Is that a known difference between Swift and Objective-C?

Comment: As mentioned already, they both are same dates. No difference at all. If you want to check, use `DateFormatter` with the same timezone.

Comment: @user1904273 It depends on your implementation of `LogDebug`.

Comment: Ok.  Something is throwing off my expected result in now.timeIntervalSince(timeFailed!) so this caught my eye.  There seems to an alternative in NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timeFailed)

Comment: Switching from now.timeIntervalSince(timeFailed!) to  NSDate().timeIntervalSince(timeFailed) solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although date() and NSDate are supposed to be the same thing, they log differently in the console whether using NSLog or a library such as LogDebug.  You should be aware of this when examining console logs.

Where there is a practical consequence to the difference between the two, is that now.timeIntervalSince(someDate!) returns a different result than NSDate().timeIntervalSince(someDate).  To avoid issues, compare apples with apples, in other words date() with date() and NSDate() with NSDate()